# checking for input only 0 or 1

Tags: c++, string

the program accepts a string consisting of 0 and 1, how can I limit the input of other numbers?
I tried using the while loop:

```
while(str<0 ||str>1){
   cout << "Enter your string: ";
   cin.getline(str, MAXLINE);
}//  in this case I can only enter 0 and 1
```

but my string can look like: "11 10 111" and therefore this method is not suitable.  How can I make an input check so that different combinations of 0 and 1 are entered, but no other digits are entered?

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int len = 0;
char str[MAXLINE];

cout << "Enter your string: ";
cin.getline(str, MAXLINE);

    while (str[0] == '\0') {
        cout << "String is empty. Try enter string again: ";
    cout << "Enter your string: ";
        cin.getline(str, MAXLINE);
}


for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i + 1] != '\0')
        len++;
    else {
        if (str[i + 1] == '\0') {
            len++;
            ++i;
        }
        if (len % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = i - len; j < i; ++j) {
                cout << str[j];
            }
            cout << "\t";
        }
        len = 0;
    }
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This is C++. There's no need for `#define` for constants or C character buffers when `std::string` is right there.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the `std::string` contains only `0` and `1` with:

```
if(str.find_first_not_of("01") != std::string::npos)
  // found invalid character
```

You could include a space in that if you allow spaces in the input.

See [std::string::find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/)